NX run-many sequential order, preventing to run the second/next app
I like to run two apps in nx monorepo in sequential order, but I don't see any luck doing that.
nx run-many -t serve -p api frontend --parallel=false
api project is started, but preventing the frontend from starting up...
stuck only on the api project:

BR

The propourse of 'serve' is to open a port and LISTEN, this WILL make the process HANG until you close it; This means that the next task will only begin when the last one has ended, but this will NEVER happen with serve;
If you want to serve more apps at the same time you should allow parallel; But this means that their outputs will be mixed in the terminal;
You could open in separate terminals and use nx run {project}:{task};
being:
# Terminal A

nx run api:serve

# Terminal B

nx run frontend:serve

Consider using a terminal multiplexer to make it easier;
